# Prevent negative number input from preset buttons

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have buttons for inputting quantities and I want to prevent users adding negative numbers. Each button is a typescript function that updates the total quantity. Is there any simple way to prevent this from going negative? HTML min="0" isn't usable as the buttons are onclick. Thanks in advance!

```
    <div class="left-container centerDiv">
         <button (click)="lessFiveDosage()"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> 5</button>
         <button (click)="lessOneDosage()"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> 1</button>
    </div>
```

```
lessOneDosage() {
    const quantity = this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity;
    if (quantity !== 1) {
      this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity = quantity - 1;
    }
    this.generateAdditionalInstructions();
  }

  lessFiveDosage() {
    const quantity = this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity;
    if (quantity !== 5) {
      this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity = quantity - 5;
    }
    this.generateAdditionalInstructions();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @David, you would need to use the updated quantity after the calculation logic of removing five or one dosage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the quantity is being set programmatically using buttons instead of manual user input, I don't see any issue with checking the adjusted value before using it.

```js
export const QUANTITY_MIN = 0;     // <-- set minimum quantity here

adjustDosage(offset: number) {
  const quantity = this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity;
  const adjusted = quantity + offset;
  this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity = 
    (adjusted < QUANTITY_MIN) ? QUANTITY_MIN : adjusted;
  this.generateAdditionalInstructions();
}
```

```html
<div class="left-container centerDiv">
  <button (click)="adjustDosage(-5)"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> 5</button>
  <button (click)="adjustDosage(-1)"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i> 1</button>
</div>
```

Note: this is pulled out of the air and could be definitely improved. And I find the usage of `this.medicationToEdit.dosages.items[0].quantity` little unsettling. Why would you want to access such a nested property directly?